# dpkg: can't install, yet dependency is already at the newest version

Tags: dpkg

On Ubuntu 16.04LTS, I'm trying to install TigerVNC:

```
monkey@Sonic ~/Downloads $ sudo dpkg -i "tigervncserver_1.7.0-1ubuntu1_i386 (1).deb" 
Selecting previously unselected package tigervncserver:i386.
(Reading database ... 259378 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack tigervncserver_1.7.0-1ubuntu1_i386 (1).deb ...
Unpacking tigervncserver:i386 (1.7.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tigervncserver:i386:
 tigervncserver:i386 depends on libtasn1-3-bin.

dpkg: error processing package tigervncserver:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tigervncserver:i386
monkey@Sonic ~/Downloads $ sudo apt-get install libtasn1-3-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libtasn1-3-bin is already the newest version (4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libtasn1-3-bin set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tigervncserver:i386 : Depends: libtasn1-3-bin:i386 but it is not installable
                       Recommends: x11-xserver-utils:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I ran `sudo apt-get -f install`, it offered to remove tigervncserver:i386.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Hard to know see http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa . If all your repos are enabled you will have to contact whoever packaged that .deb

Comment: I don't know where you got that deb, but it looks like the dependencies are incorrect. You should report the problem to the developer of the package.

Comment: I agree with dobey. There's no `libtasn1-3-bin:i386` package because that package isn't architecture-dependant. That's a packaging bug that should be reported. Bugs are also off topic on AskUbuntu. You can install `tightvncserver` from Ubuntu's repositories instead.

Answer (score 1):

`libtasn1-3-bin:i386` does not exist in Xenial, as [the package `libtasn1-3-bin` is for `all`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libtasn1-3-bin), so this package you have downloaded cannot normally be installed on Xenial. Maybe try looking for another one.